# How to read data from the URL in PHP?

Tags: php, html, flat-file

Just as an example:

```
http://domain.com/main.php(then the database file here).
```

I'm not sure what that is even called, but I can't find anything on it.

Comment: I don't know if I got it right, but you **DO NOT** want to put your db name in a link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can use GET parameters

> http://domain.com/main.php?foo=bar

Which you can get in PHP with:

```
$_GET['foo'];
```

I don't really know why you want to pass the database name in the link. Sure, it can be a parameter, but it so unsecure!

UPDATE: you may use more/multiple databases, but use then a config file. The connection names or database names do not passed in the url.

> .../main.php?state=demo&type=1, .../main.php?state=demo&type=2, etc.

```
if ($_GET['state'] == 'demo')
{
    switch ($_GET['type'])
    {
       case 1:
          $databaseName = 'demo_type_1';
       break;
       case 2:
          $databaseName = 'demo_type_2';
       break;
       default:
           throw new Exception('Wrong demo specified');

    }

    // connect to database with the name in $databaseName
}
else
{
   // Other connection
}
```

Better is to set demo state to session, so you can read out it without the url (more secure)

Comment: thank you, the reason for it is because i need to do a demo and need to show diferent database states... thank you very much.

Comment: so if i have 4 different demo's then that would be 4 different variables being $databasename1 $databasename2 etc ?

Comment: See my updated answer...

Comment: wow, thank you.. o owe you...

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to put your database name in GET requests in the query string for security reasons. But, if you still need it you can do:

http://domain.com/main.php?database_name=MyDatabase

Then on the PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $databaseName = $_GET['database_name'];
?>
```